# Counterexample-is there nondecreasing function $f:[0,\infty)\mapsto[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)<x$ for $x>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x)\neq0$, $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Is there nondecreasing function $f:[0,\infty)\mapsto[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)<x$ for $x>0$ and  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x)\neq 0,\,x>0.$$
I can see that the limits exists since it is bounded below monotonically decreasing sequence and if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x)=a,$$
then we may create new sequence $(f^n(a))$ with lower limit and so on, but I feel like it is not obvious at all that we can “touch” zero in this way.

Comment: Do you want $\lim_n f^n(x) > 0$ for some $x>0$ or all $x>0$?

Answer (score 3):

The function with the following graph is a counterexample, with $\lim_n f^n(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$: indeed the limit will be the $x$ (or $y$) coordinate of the nearest empty circle to the left.

[image: counterexample]

A formula for this function is
$$
f\bigl(\frac{1}{n}+h\bigr) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{h}{2} \quad \text{for} \quad \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{n} + h \le \frac{1}{n-1} .
$$

Comment: Thank you! Exactly wat I was thinking about, but could not write it. It is even strictly increasing (I thought about $[\frac{1}{x}]$, but it was decreasing).

Answer (score 0):

The answer and comments by Olius are right.  This answer is edited based on those.

For $b>a>0$, if we define $$\alpha(a,b) = \sup_{x \in (a,b]} \frac{f(x)}{x},$$
then we see that $$f^n (b) \leq \max \{a, b \, \alpha(a,b)^n \}.$$
Thus, if $\alpha(a,b) < 1$, then $\lim_n f^n(b) \leq a$.
If $\alpha(0,b) < 1$, then $f^n (b)$ cannot ``get stuck'' at any positive value.

But, $\alpha(a,b) < 1$ is not implied by original question because the supremum may in fact be 1.

Comment: The supremum can reach $1$ even though the ratio is always strictly smaller.

Comment: Assuming $f$ continuous then yes $\alpha(a,b)<1$. But then we could also simply note $\lim f^n(x) = f\bigl(\lim f^n(x)\bigr) < \lim f^n(x)$ if $\lim f^n(x) > 0$.